# Calculate salary based on textbox and dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, drop-down-menu

I am working in asp.net and have a text box `txtRateOfPay` and a dropdown list `ddlPayInterval`. There is a label on which yearly salary will be calculated `lblSalary`. Dropdown can contain values: Hour, Week, Month, Year, Pay Period. And when I write 1 in `txtRateOfPay`, `lblSalary` must get updated as 2080 if I selected Hour from ddl.

Formula is: If Hour is selected from ddl, then one week will have 40 hours and one year will have 52 weeks so the yearly salary is 2080.

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve this using javascript/jQuery?
I want that label to be updated when user is entering data in textbox, NOT on blur of textbox or ddl.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onkeypress` event for `textbox` and `onchange` event for `Dropdownlist`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtID" onkeypress="javascript:JSFunctionName();"></asp:TextBox> 

<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlID" onchange="javascript:JSFunctionName();">    </asp:DropDown>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function JSFunctionName() {
                document.getElementById('<%=lblID.ClientID %>').innerHTML = document.getElementById('<%=txtID.ClientID %>').value * document.getElementById('<%=ddlID.ClientID %>').value;
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: I need to call method on ddl and textbox both. For which you've written this function?

Comment: Thanks to show implemented version of my answer in asp.net ;)

Comment: onkeyup is working better as onkeydown is missing last letter

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a javascript `function` say `calculateSalary`

use `document.getElementById('text/selectboxId').value` to fetch the data and accordingly perform your operations

`document.getElementById('labelId').innerHTML = calculatedValue` will help you store value in label

call `calculateSalary function` on `onkeypress` event of textbox and `onselect` event of select boxes..

Comment: I need my label to update when key is pressed. It is not updating

Comment: @asma -  what are you writing `onkeypress` ?

Comment: `<asp:TextBox ID="txtRateOfPay" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry2" onKeyPress="CalculateYearlySalary();"></asp:TextBox>`

Comment: @asma - oops!! and what in `CalculateYearlySalary()`?

Comment: `function CalculateYearlySalary() {
            var rateOfPay = $('#<%=txtRateOfPay.ClientID%>').val();
            document.getElementById('lblYearlySalaryAmount').innerHTML = rateOfPay;
        }`

Comment: I just tested with this value, did not apply formula

Answer (score 0):

you can call the function to calculate salary in **onkeyup**. Check the SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075292/capture-client-side-text-change-event-for-asptextbox)